# Trying to set user info with gerrit's set-accont command

Tags: gerrit

I am trying to use set-account command to change a user's email address. This is what I did:

```
ssh -p 29418 root@mygerritserver.com gerrit set-accont --add-email "user1@user.com" user1
```

and I got this error:

```
gerrit: set-accont: not found
```

I am sure I typed correct url, port, username, etc.. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, **set-account**, not **set-accont**

Reference to https://git.eclipse.org/r/Documentation/cmd-set-account.html